# fread reads large integers as integer64, which are not upcasted to doubles in case of arithemetic expressions

Tags: r, data.table, fread, nanotime, bit64

When a file is read through `fread`, the columns may be read as integer64 (correctly so), but when these are multiplied with `numeric`, they are not upcasted to `numeric` (as in C++ or `integers` in `R`). While this is a documented behavior in `bit64` package. But it is not intuitive, when numbers are multiplied etc. `integer64` behaves differently compared to `integer`.

Also, `integer64` when divided against `integer` gives a `numeric` variable. So the behavior is very bizarre !

Should we then always `fread` using `colClasses = numeric` for columns to be used in arithmeric expressions with `numeric` etc ?

```
    file contents
    x,y
    111,0.3
    2147483648,0.3

    > d <- fread(file)     
    > print(d$x*d$y)
            x       y
1:        111       0.3
2: 2147483648       0.3

> as.integer64(111) * 8e-2
integer64
[1] 9
> as.integer64(111) * 8 / 1e2
8.88
```

Similarly, `quantiles` and other R functions will not behave correctly with `integer64`. This issue creeps into all classes that use `integer64` like `nanotime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of `bit64` package, see Arithmetic precision and coercion in `?bit64`:

> The fact that we introduce 64 bit long long integers – without introducing 128-bit long doubles – creates some subtle challenges

> The *multiplication* operator * coerces its first argument to integer64 but allows its second argument to be also double: the second argument is internaly coerced to 'long double' and **the result of the multiplication is returned as integer64**

```
as.integer64(111) * 8e-2
integer64
[1] 9
```

> The *division* / and power ^ operators also coerce their first argument to integer64 and coerce internally their second argument to 'long double', **they return as double**

```
as.integer64(111) * 8 / 1e2
8.88
```

To avoid this, you could set `integer64` parameter of `fread` to `"double"`. To be used with care as there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2607).

Comment: Are `integer64` intended to be used in arithmetic operations with `numeric`. If so, why ? Why does `fread` read these as `integer64` and not `numeric`, unless stated otherwise ? Why do we not report a warning when such coercion happen, so one makes a conscious choice ? If one does `quantile` of `integer64`, one does not realize if the quantiles may not be correct ?

Comment: @cryptickey, this is the default value of parameter `integer64` in `fread` : `integer64=getOption("datatable.integer64", "integer64")`.  For the why, `data.table`  team surely carefully studied pros and contras.